# How to run sqlcmd remotely on a machine which does not have SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

Is there a way in which we can run sqlcmd on a machine without having SSMS.

Comment: I think several question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290903/run-sqlcmd-without-having-sql-server-installed

Answer (score 2):

If you follow [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978) for `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Feature Pack` , you should be able to download it for the machine without needing to install SQL server.

Also, see [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=36433) for `Microsoft Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server`
 which might be better.

Comment: Agreed.  Our "builc machine" has these...to auto deploy some databases using sqlcmd.  No SSMS required!