# Executing set of SQL queries using batch file?

Tags: sql-server, database, batch-file, cmd

I am using a SQL Server database. I have these SQL queries:

```
Delete from TableA;
Delete from TableB;
Delete from TableC;
Delete from TableD;
Delete from TableE;
```

Is it possible to run these scripts using a batch file? The database is a remote database.

Thanks!

Comment: Open a cmd prompt and type `sqlcmd /?`

Comment: Nagaraj, it was for oracle. Now the question for sqlserver.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Save the commands in a `.SQL` file, ex: `ClearTables.sql`, say in your `C:\temp` folder.

**Contents of** `C:\Temp\ClearTables.sql`

```
Delete from TableA;
Delete from TableB;
Delete from TableC;
Delete from TableD;
Delete from TableE;
```

Then use `sqlcmd` to execute it as follows. Since you said the database is remote, use the following syntax (after updating for your server and database instance name).

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> -i C:\Temp\ClearTables.sql
```

For example, if your remote computer name is SQLSVRBOSTON1 and Database instance name is MyDB1, then the command would be.

```
sqlcmd -E -S SQLSVRBOSTON1\MyDB1 -i C:\Temp\ClearTables.sql
```

Also note that `-E` specifies default authentication. If you have a user name and password to connect, use `-U` and `-P` switches.

You will execute all this by opening a `CMD` command window.

**Using a Batch File.**

If you want to save it in a batch file and double-click to run it, do it as follows.

Create, and save the `ClearTables.bat` like so.

```
echo off
sqlcmd -E -S SQLSVRBOSTON1\MyDB1 -i C:\Temp\ClearTables.sql
set /p delExit=Press the ENTER key to exit...:
```

Then double-click it to run it. It will execute the commands and wait until you press a key to exit, so you can see the command output.

Comment: +1 The question says "The database is remote database."... can you adjust the command line?

Comment: Shiva, Thanks much for your answer. Can i place -E -S SQLSVRBOSTON1\MyDB1 -i C:\Temp\ClearTables.sql in batch file and just double click on it ?

Comment: Yes. Save it as a `.BAT` file. You might want to put a pause at the next line so that the CMD window doesn't run the delete and exit, and you are able to see the output before closing the window. I updated my answer for this.

Comment: This will help http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2478/connecting-to-sql-server-using-sqlcmd-utility/

Comment: Shiva, can i use same sqlcmd to run the queries against oracle db?

Comment: Oracle's command line utility is called `sqlplus` not `sqlcmd`. So for oracle, you will have to have something like the following content in the batch file. You have to tweak this, but this will get you started `@echo off
sqlplus -s -l user/password@MyDb @C:\Temp\ClearTables.sql > DeleteTable.log`

Comment: While this solution will work, you have check error codes if you want this to be a job.  Otherwise, how do you know it completed.  See article for more - http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=91064.0

Comment: how to do it in local database, i used : `sqlcmd -E -S localhost\sqlexpress -i C:\test.sql -o C:\TestResults.txt` in script i am creating table  i have `USE [TestDB]
GO`, but generated `txt`file i get this error:`Changed database context to 'TestDB'.`

Answer (score 5):

Check out SQLCMD command line tool that comes with SQL Server. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Comment: Bate Tech, i have to run the batch file in the machine in which no sql server is installed. I have to run it on remote database. Database is not there in the machine in which i am executing the batch file.

Comment: Use the :connect statement.  This also can be done in SSMS using the SQLCMD window type.

Comment: @user755806: You can use sqlcmd's `-S` parameter to choose the server

Comment: Use powershell below.  It is installed on every Windows 7 machine and above or install the SSMS management pack.

Comment: @user755806 I updated my answer for remote database. Check it out.

Comment: You can install SQLCMD without having SQL Server installed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872387/how-to-run-sqlcmd-remotely-on-a-machine-which-does-not-have-ssms

Answer (score 2):

Use the **SQLCMD** utility.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

There is a connect statement that allows you to swing from database server A to server B in the same batch.

:Connect server_name[\instance_name] [-l timeout] [-U user_name [-P password]]
Connects to an instance of SQL Server. Also closes the current connection.

On the other hand, if you are familiar with **PowerShell**, you can programmatic do the same.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281954(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Different ways:

1. Using SQL Server Agent (If local instance)
   schedule a job in sql server agent with a new step having type as "T-SQL" then run the job.
2. Using SQLCMD 
   To use SQLCMD refer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx
3. Using SQLPS 
   To use SQLPS refer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280450.aspx

Comment: Using SQL Server Agent will not help.  The database is remote.  You will need a linked server in addition.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA That's correct (will update the answer). but a possible way to run scripts in local instance.

Comment: Looks like the SQLPS link is being deprecated and redirects to the new version of SQLPS Module https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-ver15