# Batch File to run .sql file in Remote Machine and Update Database

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I want to create batch file to execute all my .sql scripts. I have scripts in .SQL file.

**update.sql**

```
use DatabaseName;
INSERT INTO alarm_day (al_id,al_day,activate) VALUES (12,'test','test')
```

**update.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
SET MYSQL_EXE="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe"
SET DB_USER=root
SET DB_PWD=password

CALL %MYSQL_EXE% --user=%DB_USER% --password=%DB_PWD% < update.sql
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO Error executing SQL file
```

above Code is working on localhost, But what we need to do when Database is on different server(Host).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing set of SQL queries using batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554062/executing-set-of-sql-queries-using-batch-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use as per below-

```
CALL %MYSQL_EXE% -h <remote_server_ip> --user=%DB_USER% --password=%DB_PWD% < update.sql
```

Make sure you have permissions on db server.