# Batch file script for sqlcmd

Tags: database, batch-file, sqlcmd

I'm looking for a way to make the below commands a bit more automated. I would like to be able to use just a simple batch file if possible.

sqlcmd /S localhost\SQLEXPRESS /U [dbusername] /P [dbpassword]

1> drop database datastore

2> go

Comment: When you read the help file for the `SQLCMD` did you not see the `-i` option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing set of SQL queries using batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554062/executing-set-of-sql-queries-using-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
sqlcmd /S localhost\SQLEXPRESS /U [dbusername] /P [dbpassword] <cmds.txt
```

where `cmds.txt` is a file containing your commands (the drop and the go commands).